# Loading items into array from SQL Server

Tags: javascript, performance

The program we are working at has the following function:

```
function loadItem(arrayValues,arrayNames) {
    var j=document.getElementById('itemSelect').options.length;
    for(var i=0;i<arrayValues.length;i++) {
        if(!existsElement(document.getElementById('itemSelect'),arrayValues[i])) {
            document.getElementById('itemSelect').options[j]=new Option(arrayValues[i]+" - "+arrayNames[i],arrayValues[i],null);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

This fills a list that is later used to filter a search.

It was originally designed for small arrays (up to 25 elements) and it worked perfectly.

Now, I'm trying to use it to fill with the whole contents of a SQL table (about 9500 elements), I take the data from the DB with Java, transfer it to Javascript via AJAX and parse that List into two arrays that can be used with this function. That takes about a second, but then this function takes about 20 seconds to complete.

Why is it that slow, and what can I do to improve it?

Comment: Please reveal more details about how this method is used and what else your page is doing etc. Maybe there are some automatic event handlers... who knows. We need more info.

Comment: I think I see where this is going...

Comment: Hey, the code for `existsElement` would be useful.

Comment: As it currently stands, this question's title leaves something to be wanted. The title should explain what the code does, not what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

## Main issues

### Access

- DOM operations take time. You're selecting the element N^2 + 1 times. This can be reduced to 1: `document.getElementById('itemSelect')`
- You're constantly getting `arrayValues[i]`, which only needs to be done once.

### Style

- You should put spaces after commas: `arg, arg2`
- You should put spaces before and after operations, for readability: `var name = value`
- Spaces after semicolons: `i < length; i++`

## Rewrite

```
function loadItem(arrayValues, arrayNames) {
    var itemSelect = document.getElementById('itemSelect'),
        j = itemSelect.options.length;
    for(var i = 0, length = arrayValues.length; i < length; i++) {
        let val = arrayValues[i];
        if(!existsElement(itemSelect, val)) {
            itemSelect.options[j] = new Option(val + " - " + arrayNames[i], val, null);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM operations are costly, so use variables.

```
var is=document.getElementById('itemSelect');
for(var i=0;i<arrayValues.length;i++) {
    if(!existsElement(is,arrayValues[i])) {
        is.options.push(new Option(arrayValues[i]+" - "+arrayNames[i],arrayValues[i],null));
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the `.options` property is empty, which may not be what the author wants.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I am no JS expert. Is it because I also changed `[length]` to `.push`?

Comment: `[index]` sets the value for that index, `.push` appends a value to the end of it. Yes, it is because of that change.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix then this should be the same functionality as that of the OP's: if not existing, push a new one to the options. BTW your code is more nicely styled.